# WCF client doesn't work after upgrade web application to core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, .net-core

Could somebody explain why WCF client doesnt work after upgrading web application project to 3.0 or 3.1. I tested on three simple projects, which created from visual studio: new project => asp.net core MVC app. There is test modifications to boiler plate code of projects:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly WCFGetClient _getClient;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _getClient = new WCFGetClient();            
    }

    //some boiler plate code code
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> Privacy()
    {
        _ = await _getClient.GetAsync("some info", false);
        return View();
    }
```

WCF Code:

```
public DbModel GetAsync(string Id, bool withDeleted)
    {
        return withDeleted
            ? _db.Table.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == Id)
            : _db.Table.Any(c => c.Id == Id && c.Deleted == false)
            ? _db.Table.Single(c => c.Id == Id)
            : null;
    }
```

In debug mode project builded for core 2.2 get response from WCF service (.net 4.7.2). But another two projects (3.0 & 3.1) get exception:

> SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software
> in your host machine.

> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
> established connection was aborted by the software in your host
> machine..
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()

WCF hosted on windows server 2012R2 IIS 6.2.

I tried to update libs System.ServiceModel.Duplex, System.ServiceModel.Federation, System.ServiceModel.Http, System.ServiceModel.NetTcp, System.ServiceModel.Primitives, System.ServiceModel.Security to 4.10.0 **doesn't help**.

**UPD #0** I tried to run this WCF service in IIS 10 on windows 10 professional and re-run tests with my solution(core 2.2, 3.0 and 3.1) and wcf answered without errors. Whoa... Keep digging

Comment: The error stems from inside `WCFGetClient`, which seems to be some code that you have written (and is not available for us to see). The relevant details are thus more likely to be there, then in the controller code that is just using it. You need to post the code for `WCFGetClient` (or some stripped down version that exhibits the same error).

Comment: @Christian.K Code work's fine. There are 3 projects in my solution which work with same wcf service. core 2.2 call for service method and it return result. Another projects (core 3.0 and 3.1) with same arguments passed to the same service return the error.

Comment: So, you have a .NET Core 2.2 project that works with `WCFGetClient`, and two .NET Core 3.x projects that don't. Why do you think that `WCFGetClient` "works fine then"? The controller code - from all that can be seen by the fragment you posted - looks innocent enough to not be the issue. You're right to some extend. It could also be configuration or other issues. All of which we cannot see from your question.